# Polars: Manipulation on columns by 'dtype' creating multiple new columns

Tags: python, python-polars

```
data = {"col1": ['2020/01/01', '2020/02/01'], "col2": ['2020/01/01', '2020/02/01']}
df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema={"col1": pl.Utf8, "col2": pl.Utf8})

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('col1').str.to_datetime(),
    pl.col('col2').str.to_datetime()
)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.DATETIME_DTYPES).dt.year()
)
```

With the given code I want to create new columns for every column selected by `pl.DATETIME_DTYPES` with the extracted year. For a single column I would apply `.alias()` but what to do for potentially ***n*** new columns? Any *generic* way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can use the methods in the [`pl.Expr.name`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/name.html) namespace. The most flexible method would be [`pl.Expr.name.map`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.map.html#polars.Expr.name.map), but there is also [`pl.Expr.name.prefix`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.prefix.html#polars.Expr.name.prefix), [`pl.Expr.name.suffix`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.prefix.html#polars.Expr.name.suffix), etc.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.DATETIME_DTYPES).dt.year().name.map(lambda s: s + "_year")
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ col1                ┆ col2                ┆ col1_year ┆ col2_year │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i32       ┆ i32       │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020      ┆ 2020      │
│ 2020-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020      ┆ 2020      │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```